# How can a formula be used in scalc (Apache OpenOffice) to count cells with content, while the count should stop at the first empty cell?

Tags: count, range, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc, calc

Here (https://www.howtoexcel.org/formulas/how-to-find-the-position-of-the-first-non-blank-cell-in-a-range/) is a source for Excel where the following formula is described:

```
{=MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(B3:B9),0)}
```

The count should stop at b because the following cell is empty or contains no printable character. The result should be 2.

```
=COUNTA(A30:A50) ; A29
a
b

c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use a count function because we can subtract 1 from the matched index to get the count. Also, to find the first blank cell, the search criterion should be true, not false.

```
=MATCH(TRUE();ISBLANK(A30:A50);0)-1
a
b

c
```

Result: `2`

In LibreOffice Calc, this works when entered normally. In Apache OpenOffice, it must be entered as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.